# How to get n number of records using spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have seen many examples as follows. But I am not getting any solution for my problem.

I am using the below code to get the all users.

```
List<User> users = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
 "select * from user",
      new RowMapper<User>() {
           public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                    user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                    return user;
           }
         });
```

But the problem with the above code is, if I have 10 Million records in the users table, I will not be able to keep the data in a list.

So I was using `fetchSource(100)` function on `jdbcTemplate`. 
I am not able to get the all records, it is stopped in between.

Please suggest what to do.

[edited]
To add to the below questions, I am indexing the data from the oracle DB table to elsticsearch. I do not want to process one by one because, will be very poor to index 10 million records. It is not a web application, it is standalone program, which is build on spring boot.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Al records or a part of the records, which database are you using...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to process all rows one by one without keeping them in memory you can use a `RowCallbackHandler`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html

If you only want to fetch a few rows just add a limit to your query `select * from user limit 100`